# State machine for Simulator

Tags: c++, design-patterns, uml

Hi all
I am working for the simulator of the gateway.gateway is a device which is connected with camera and stream video to the server whenever server request it.

Each gateway is connected with more than one camrea. Simulator can simulate 1000 gateway.

Now here each gateway has state like booting,disconnected,ready etc....so I have created state transition diagram for that but Will there be any state transition for simulator as well.
I dont know my question is correct or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say *no*. Normally in discrete-event simulation the simulation itself isn't represented as an object, nor does the overall simulation have distinct states of its own.